# JQuery Ajax call to ASP.NET MVC API returns error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an api controller `CustomerController` that returns customers data:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using CustomerMngmt.Models;

namespace CustomerMngmt.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly Customer[] _customer =
    {
        new Customer
        {
            Id = 1,
            firstName = "Florian",
            lastName = "Hofmeister",
            emailAddress = "florianhofmeister@test.de",
            company = "Germany",
            pictureURL = "......jpg"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Id = 2,
            firstName = "Svenja",
            lastName = "Hofmeister",
            emailAddress = "svenjahofmeister@test.de",
            company = "Germany",
            pictureURL = "......jpg"
        },
        new Customer
        {
            Id = 3,
            firstName = "Marvin",
            lastName = "Hofmeister",
            emailAddress = "marvinhofmeister@test.de",
            company = "Germany",
            pictureURL = "......jpg"
        }
    };



        public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            return _customer;
        }

        public Customer GetCustomerById(int id)
        {
            var customer = _customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I load data in javascript with:

```
function loadCustomer() {

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:54172/api/customers',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{},
        success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var customer = new customer(
                    '1',
                    data[i].id,
                    data[i].firstName,
                    data[i].lastname,
                    data[i].companyName,
                    data[i].emailAddress,
                    data[i].pictureURL);

                self.customers.push(customer);
            }
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + "TEST");
            console.log(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + "TEST");
        }
    });
}
```

and my problem is that the function don't load the elements from the controller. Instead I get an error message `[object Object]errorTEST`.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your API. Try to change the `url` to `url: '/api/customers'`.

Comment: is your API calls going fine?

Comment: Check your network tab in the console to see the actual response and error.

Comment: can i do this when i have the webpage and the javascript on another folder on my pc?

Comment: i have check it and firebug say me the xml things they i needet as answere and the normal networkanalys say me SyntaxError: JSON.parse unexpected edn of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: can you post that line where it says SyntaxError: JSON.parse,

and in this line, 
            for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {

what is customer?, you're using "data" variable to return data from ajax calls

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)  is the rigth code but the proplem isn go away

Comment: Ahm now i become 2 of the error message in the console: Cross-origin request blocked : The same-origin rule prohibits the external resource at http : // localhost : 54172 / api / customers to read . This can be achieved by the resource in the same domain will be pushed or CORS is activated.  before i become 1

Comment: and now i become an error 405 Method not Allowed after i have add it

Comment: firefox and chrome let see me the xml data and ie will download an json data wich i can open in editor and there are the data saved in arrays

Comment: where is your javascript `customer` class? `new customer(...`  Do you have that same Error handler elsewhere?

Comment: self.customers = ko.observableArray();

Comment: and javascript is an OOP language also i dont need an class this is the class

Comment: iam `new`ing up an array element

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63941/discussion-on-question-by-florian-hofmeister-jquery-ajax-call-to-asp-net-mvc-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url in your ajax doesn't match any controller or action. If the script is in a cshtml file you can use the url helper to build the url.  For security reasons, I recommend using POST instead GET if you have authentication in this. Last, you can use responseText to see the actual error message.

```
$.ajax({
    url: @Url.Action("Customers", "GetAllCustomers"), // or try 'http://localhost:54172/Customers/GetAllCustomers'
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var customer = new customer(
                '1',
                data[i].id,
                data[i].firstName,
                data[i].lastname,
                data[i].companyName,
                data[i].emailAddress,
                data[i].pictureURL);

            self.customers.push(customer);
        }
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        alert(x.responseText + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + "TEST");
        console.log(x.responseText + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + "TEST");
    }
});
```

Comment: that cant be the proplem because the ie give me the rigth data

Answer (score 0):

try changing the url to this one --> ControllerName/Method

Comment: Are you trying to display the customers data into a different view or partial view? If that's the case then why don't you just create a partial view that has a viewmodel where it would load all your stuff?

Comment: no iam writing an SPA one html data and so i have the listview for the htmldata

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you should obviously change url in ajax (/controller/action)  and return json from your api controller. Therefore i don't see action named customers in your code.

Comment: i dont know what you mean

Comment: @cassteam There's no need for an action named customers nor to return json. Web API automatically routes GET method to actions that start by `Get` and returns json based on the Accept header. Check [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the API, I suspect it's your JavaScript that's blowing up when trying to create the `customer` collection.  Try adding this to the JavaScript:

```
function customer(id, firstname, lastname, companyname, email, pic) {
            this.Id = id;
            this.FirstName = firstname;
            this.LastName = lastname;
            this.Company = companyname;
            this.email = email;
            this.Pic = pic;
        }
```

And alter the variable you're creating, I have changed to `cus` in my example...

```
var cus = new customer(
                        '1',
                        data[i].id,
                        data[i].firstName,
                        data[i].lastname,
                        data[i].companyName,
                        data[i].emailAddress,
                        data[i].pictureURL);

                    self.customers.push(cus);
```